# Como relacionar instância de categoria em uma instância de produto no PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho 2 classes no PHP, Produto e Categoria.

A seguir o código de cada.

Produto.php

```
class Produto {
     public $nome;
     public $categoria;
}
```

Categoria.php

```
class Categoria {
     public $nome;
}
```

Nesse caso, o que apenas quero fazer, é referenciar a categoria que será instanciada posteriormente no atributo categoria do produto. Como posso fazer isso?

Só esclarecendo uma coisa, um produto precisa apenas ter uma categoria, não precisa ter mais de uma.

Comment: Você quer que seu objeto `Produto` receba o objeto `Categoria`? Se sim, está certo já, basta incluir o caminho da classe `Categoria` e tratá-la normalmente como objeto dentro de `Produto`.

Comment: Você no título diz que quer adicionar 2 categorias em um produto, porem não esclareceu isso na descrição, seria isso mesmo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma usando encapsulamento, onde ser define todos as propriedades da classe como private ou protected(Caso exista uma relação de herança) e ser cria os métodos que ficaram responsáveis por manipular essas propriedades, assim garantido a integridade dos dados, que nesse caso são os métodos set's e get's, onde:

**Set's**: Sâo os métodos responsável por atribuir os valores nas propriedades da classe, onde isso permiti que você possa tratar os valores antes que eles sejam atribuídos para suas propriedades, assim garantido uma segurança maior da integridade dos dados da sua classe.

**Get's**: São os métodos responsável por permitir a leitura das propriedades fora da classe, assim possibilitando que você crie só os get's para as propriedades que você queira que sejam lidas fora da classe.

Classe Produto:

```
<?php

class Produto {

  private $nome;
  private $categoria;

  //Método construtor da classe Produto
  public function __construct($nome, Categoria $categoria) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
    $this->categoria = $categoria;
  }

  public function setNome($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function getNome() {
    return $this->nome;
  }

  public function setCategoria(Categoria $categoria) {
    $this->categoria = $categoria;
  }

  public function getCategoria() {
    return $this->categoria;
  }

}
```

Classe Categoria:

```
<?php

class Categoria {

  private $nome;

  //Método construtor da classe Categoria
  public function __construct($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function setNome($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function getNome() {
    return $this->nome;
  }

}
```

Arquivo de teste:

```
<?php

require_once 'Produto.php';
require_once 'Categoria.php';

$categoria = new Categoria('Livro');
$produto = new Produto('Sistema de Banco de Dados', $categoria);

echo 'Produto: ' . $produto->getNome();
echo '<br>';
echo 'Categoria: ' . $produto->getCategoria()->getNome();
```

Comment: a melhor proposta até o momento, visto que utiliza *getters* e *setters*, seria bom adicionar uma explicação do motivo, `+1`

Comment: Essa proposta está bem clara mesmo. Aqui eu não deveria usar também um método destrutor também?

Comment: O destrutor não é obrigatório. Utilize apenas caso seja necessário finalizar alguma conexão, ou tirar algo de memória, ou gerar logs, etc

Comment: php permite tipagem agora? Interessante, nem sabia, to desatualizado demais hehe

Comment: Sim, mas só com indução de tipo utilizando classe.

Answer (score 3):

Aconselho você a utilizar construtores, se eu entendi bem a propriedade categoria no Produto é uma outra classe "Categoria", então pode fazer assim:

```
class Categoria {
 public $nome;

 public __construct($nome) {
  $this->nome = $nome;
 }
}
```

Ai quando você for criar um produto você pode colocar assim:

```
$produto = new Produto();
$produto->categoria = new Categoria("Nome");
```

Espero ter entendido corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Para que produto tenha várias categorias se entendi direito, basta fazer o seguinte:

```php
class Produto{
    public $nome;
    public $categoria = array();

    public adicionarCategoria(Categoria $Categoria)
    {
        $this->categoria[] = $Categoria;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

Recomendo adicionar o método __toString() para facilitar na hora de trabalhar a saída para usuário.

```php
class Categoria{
    public $nome;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

Para adicionar uma categoria em um produto ficaria assim:

```php
$Categoria1 = new Categoria();
$Categoria1->nome = 'Categoria 1';

$Categoria2 = new Categoria();
$Categoria2->nome = 'Categoria 2';

$Produto = new Produto();
$Produto->adicionarCategoria($Categoria1);
$Produto->adicionarCategoria($Categoria2);
```

Comment: Sua explicação está muito boa, mas não era necessariamente adicionar mais de uma categoria o que perguntei. Porém pode servir e muito caso eu precise implementar isso. Sua resposta vai ajudar bastante em outra situação.

Comment: Tudo bem, fiquei na dúvida pois citou 2 categorias no título.